# What parameters does Stack Exchange use to decide to create meta sites?

Tags: support, per-site-meta

We have dedicated meta sites for the community such as Stack Overflow, Hinduism, etc. while some sites such as Super User, Mathematics, etc. do not have meta sites?

Are there any parameters (traffic, questions per day or something) for creating a dedicated meta site?

**UPDATE**

As we don't have **meta user** option directly, I thought some sites do not have their dedicated meta sites. But, I got the answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338683/484288)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Every site but meta has meta sites.Only thing is for SU - its meta.superuser.com rather than say superuser.meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Well, stackoverflow.com, serverfault.com and askubuntu.com have domain names that aren’t of the form X.stackexchange.com, but rather S.com, and so they all have Meta sites whose names are of the form meta.S.com rather than X.meta.stackexchange.com.  Ditto for mathoverflow.net.

Comment: That's due to https certs

Comment: Yeah, I understand.   My point is that your comment made it sound like Super User was a unique special case.

Answer (score 3):

## Only Meta.SE doesn't have a Meta site.

Every site on the network has an associated Meta site except MSE. Math.Se has its Meta [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/) for example. You can find the Meta for an associated site by going to that site and clicking the help icon and then "Meta". Or, you can click on the network icon, and the associated Meta will be shown underneath whatever community you are on.

The only weird one is Stack Apps, which is, essentially, its own Meta site. MSE, serves as a Meta site for StackExchange.com and therefore doesn't have a Meta associated with it (but also essentially acts as its own when needed).

Comment: Well, Meta Meta Stack Exchange was a silly place. It had to go

Comment: Meta meta means murder murder.

Comment: Perhaps add something like: Meta Stack Exchange is its own meta site (such questions are qualified by using tag "meta").

Comment: @PeterMortensen How's that look?

Comment: Meta.SE is the Meta site for SE.com, technically.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Ironically, that's really very meta. :)

Comment: [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) doesn't have a Meta site either. For all other sites it should be correct, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

You can access any Stack Exchange site's Meta by clicking on the hamburger menu in the upper right corner - you will see the site name at the top, and its meta immediately below; that's a link to the meta. Below is how it appears for Super User on Chrome on Windows:

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't call it a hamburger menu. Isn't it how the Stack Exchange logo is at that resolution?

Comment: @PeterMortensen - Yes, that's the SE logo in black-and-white and at low resolution, but the last time I got into an involved discussion of the top bar and its icons, somehow it ended up being referred to as the hamburger menu, so I've been referring to it as such since.

Comment: It's hamburgery enough!