# Build a per-site meta for Meta Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request, meta, per-site-meta

There are some posts about complaints from users of moderator/user actions on their posts.

I think a per-site meta is needed here for this kind of problems; because this is a place for people to ask primarily about the site's features.  Posts for complaints are making the community a little bad-looking I think (e.g. make it to go to the margin if these posts are high).

Comment: It's not different. Same characteristics

Comment: You can't have a Meta for a Meta.  A Meta site for asking questions about the Meta site for all of Stack Exchange, including per-site Metas, seems kinda unnecessary.  Also, what would you name it?  Meta2 SE?

Comment: @Richard Yes, that's right

Comment: @Ollie You can name it anything

Comment: You'll enjoy this *duplicate* were the question is completely different, but [one answer is mostly an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338681/282094) to this question.

Comment: We have [the meta tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta) for meta questions on meta... - *"Use this tag to ask questions about this very site, a.k.a. MSE. In some sense, the [meta] tag is Meta-Meta Stack Exchange. "*

Answer (score 5):

I do not think that there is a case for an additional site on which to post “complaints from users of moderator/user actions on their posts” because they can already be posted here.

In general, any unfounded complaints seem to be quickly adjudged as such by downvoting, and often by deleting.

For legitimate complaints to be well received they should always be focused on a behavior rather than personalized against one or more users.